# Is it possible to have both LEMP and LAMP in the local system?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, nginx, lamp, fedora

i am newbie in using linux system and i want to know whether i can run both [LEMP](http://library.linode.com/lemp-guides/fedora-14) and [LAMP](http://www.lamphowto.com/) in the same system. I am using fedora 14. if i can install means, is there any possiblity that my existing file which used Apache(LAMP) will get affected.

Comment: if the L in both cases is linux, the M in both cases is mysql, and the P in both cases is PHP, then I think the question would make a lot more sense if you ignored those and just asked "Is it possible to have both nginx and apache in the local system". This is the first time I've ever seen someone spell nginx with an E o_O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install the both LEMP and LAMP  in same machine. But, the application service should be listen on different port.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have two services listen on the same port. But as long as you configure one or the other not to use port 80, it ought to be possible.

Comment: ....so you can run one of the servers to proxy specific URLs to the other, or run a proxy in front of both.